# Hide APN notification ONLY when app is in background?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging for my push notifications, which uses APN in their back-end.

When app is in **foreground**, `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is called and notification is not shown, that is perfect.

When application is **killed**, `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is not called but notification is shown, that is alright too.

However, when application is in **background**, both `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is called and notification is shown. How do I hide it and keep only `didReceiveRemoteNotification` get called?

Here is how my payload looks like:

```
$fields = array(
     'registration_ids' => $tokens,
     'data' => $message,
     'content_available' => true,
     'priority' => 'high',
     'notification' => array('body' => 'notifbody', 'title' => 'testtitle', 'sound' => 'default')
    );
```

Comment: Did you get an answer? Is it impossible?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
      UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
        // user tapped notification while app was in background
    if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive || state == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
         // go to screen relevant to Notification content
    } else {
         // App is in UIApplicationStateActive (running in foreground)
         // perhaps show an UIAlertView
    }
}
```

Secondly,
When you call method **- (void)registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationType)types** you should indicate appropriate type of argument. If you want to display alert when system receive push-notification for your device then you should pass **UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert**.

Also you can combine types and pass it in that argument: **UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge.**

Remove Alert, if you don't want to get an alert from top.

Hope it will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: This method is empty in my code, I am not showing anything myself, APN generates and shows notification

Comment: are you talking about notification which comes from top of iOS, in notification center? @Gintas_

Comment: @Gintas_, check answer now, you can set type of notfication you want when you register. So, you can have choice of not choosing alert, remove alert one.

Comment: But I need alert when app is killed. Just not when it's in background

Comment: Can you try to change type before termination, lets say didAppTerminate method ...